# Mongodb schema design for task

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, mongodb-query, database-schema

I am working on a project which allow user to create task and other user(service provider) can provide them quotation and later let the user decide which service provider is suitable for them.

Here is the service schema:

```
var ServiceSchema = new Schema({
  address: String,
  quotations:[{
    service_provider:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    price: Number,
    date: Date
}],
  customers :[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User', childPath:'services_need'}],
});
```

and here is the user schema

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
   name:String,
   password:String, 
   email:String,
   phone:String,
   token:String,
   services_need:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Service'}],
   services_provide:[{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Service'}],
});
```

The question is that is this in best practise? Any other rules of design I break?
Also , do I need to hold the reference of User in Service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do sub document relationships like that without any problems.

What do you mean by "do I need to hold the reference in User "? Please elaborate

Comment: What I mean is it necessary for User to holder the reference for the Service?

Comment: Looks like you have a reference to the user from the service and a reference to the Services (array) from the User.  There isnt enough information for me to tell you rather I believe your design is right or wrong.   I dont see anything wrong with how you have it.  You can easily "populate()" the sub documents in your current design.